# Unable to simulate deadlock using example in book

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex

I am reading "Concurrency in Go: Tools and Techniques for Developers" by Katherine Cox-Buday, and am stuck at a very simple example that is meant to simulate a deadlock. The snippet looks like this.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    printSum := func(a, b *somevar) {
        defer wg.Done()
        a.mu.Lock()
        defer a.mu.Unlock()
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

        b.mu.Lock()
        defer b.mu.Unlock()

        fmt.Printf("sum is - %d \n", a.val + b.val)
    }

    var a, b somevar
    a.val = 50
    b.val = 300
    wg.Add(2)
    go printSum(&a, &b)
    go printSum(&a, &b)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

[Figure describing how the deadlock occurs, as per the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS8hl.png)

However, when I try to run this, I always get the output.

```
sum is - 352 
sum is - 354
```

In this example, will the second instance of printSum wait for the lock on var a and only proceed when the lock is acquired, or will it move on and acquire the lock on var b? 
The book is from 2015, so have there been changes to the language behaviour that makes the example invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong. Deadlock is triggered by circular locking, and that will only happen if you lock the two locks in different order. So, do this instead:

```
go printSum(&a, &b)
go printSum(&b, &a)
```

When the lock ordering is like above, the first `printSum` will lock `a` and the second will lock `b`, and then they'll wait for the other lock to release, which will never happen.

Comment: You are right. I seem to have misread the example in the book. Thank you.